# How to get the specific string from the HTML tag code and check existence of <img> tag in a string?

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I've two HTML codes. One of them is definitely going to present in a variable `$text` as follows :

```
//First HTML code 

$text = <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/vuHOZ3n8ToyvQUDQ03zi">vuHOZ3n8ToyvQUDQ03zi</a>

        <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/vuHOZ3n8ToyvQUDQ03zi">Download</a>;

    //Second HTML code
$text = <a title="" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xdA3uDwdTWydvK7ISlws"><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xdA3uDwdTWydvK7ISlws" height="150px" width="150px"></a>

        <a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xdA3uDwdTWydvK7ISlws" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>;
```

If first HTML code is present the variable `$type` should contain the value 'file' like `$type = 'file';`

If second HTML code is present the variable `$type` should contain the value 'image' like `$type = 'image';`

I want to achieve this using HTML Parsing.

In first case, I want the string 'file' from the class attribute of first anchor tag `class="comment_attach_file_link"`

In second case, I want the string 'image' only if the `<img>` tag is present in the HTML code.

How should I do this in an efficient way in PHP? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strpos() to do that:

```
<?php 

$text = '<a title="" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xdA3uDwdTWydvK7ISlws"><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xdA3uDwdTWydvK7ISlws" height="150px" width="150px"></a>

        <a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xdA3uDwdTWydvK7ISlws" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>';

if (strpos($text,'class="comment_attach_file_link"') !== false) {
    echo 'file';
}
elseif (strpos($text,'<img') !== false) {
    echo 'image';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily through jquery "$('#id').attr('class')". You will get the class value.
The same with the image.

Comment: I want to do it using PHP only.